# TFS build error - process cannot access

Tags: tfs

When I am trying to buid on TFS build server I got the following error:
Error CS2012: Cannot open 'xx.dll' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'xx.dll' because it is being used by another process.'

Could anyone please help out with that?

Comment: I restarted the TFS build machine, anyway the error occurs.

Comment: do you have anti-virus running ? I have found this could lock files some times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a web application or anything of the like make sure that your server process (usually IISExpress or something) is not being run.

Kill all the processes that maybe consuming your compiled code.

Alternatively, you can download [Lockhunter](http://lockhunter.com/) and see which program is locking that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately I am not building web project.

Comment: What are you building?